# Difficulty with Conversion of Date Time to JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I am trying to convert a `list<T>` into JSON data and then binding to Jqgrid.

The Problem is that list collection contains one of the column as DateTime.

When i see the resultant JSON response, the date time is not properly serialized. Its coming like this:

```
 /Date(1267408935000)/
```

How to convert list collection into JSON data properly when it contains date time columns.

Please help..

Comment: How do you want he json date to be formatted?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? If you use `formatter: "data"` then jqGrid in many last version will make the corresponding conversion automatically.

Comment: @Oleg.i am using the latest version of JqGrid.

Comment: @Sam Leach i would like it to be converted to .NET date format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `formatter: "date"` for the corresponding column definition in `colModel` then jqGrid will make the corresponding conversion automatically. The problem could be only if you use some very old version of jqGrid (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3achange#additions_and_changes5) which described that the corresponding support was introduced starting with jqGrid 3.8.2).

Comment: @Oleg.I tried putting formatter:"data". But, still the date time is  not properly displayed.

Comment: @Avinash: Sorry for typing error. One should use [formatter:"date"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) instead of `formatter:"data"`. I fixed the text of my answer.

Comment: @Oleg..i am getting only date..is it possible to get the same format as that of .net Date Time. Is there any way to specify the format..

Comment: @Avinash: You should use `newformat` to specify the format of date which you need to display to the user. Try for example `formatoptions: {newformat: "n/j/Y g:i:s A"}` or `formatoptions: {newformat: "ISO8601Long"}`. I am not sure which format of date are typically used in your country.

Comment: @Oleg..Perfect..Exactly the format that i wanted..Thanks again

Comment: @Oleg..can you please help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380019/unable-to-see-images-icons-on-jqgrid

Answer (score 2):

When you say it's "not properly serialized" - that looks okay to me. That's one format for JSON dates, coming from the Javascript `Date` constructor taking a "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" as a parameter. So the value you've given is March 1st 2010 02:02:15 UTC for example.

I'd *expect* the Javascript deserializing this data to be absolutely fine - but of course that's not necessarily the case... If it's really causing problems for you, read [Scott  Hanselman's blog post about JSON date/time formats](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) - in particular, it explains how you can swap out the JSON formatter to be [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), which uses an ISO-8601 format by default.

Answer (score 0):

Create class with **string** property instead of **DateTime**.

```
public class MyJsonModel
{
   public string DateTimeString { get;set; }
}

var model = new MyJsonModel();
model.DateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"); //Any format you like
```