# Unable to see Images/icons on jqgrid

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, jqgrid

I am using JqGrid in my Asp.net MVC Web Application.

I have placed all the java script files under `Scripts` folder and all the css and images in the `Content` folder as per the directory structure of an normal MVC Application.

But, here the problem is that i was not able to see the images on the grid. the CSS is working fine but icons for paging,sorting are not visible.

Can any one help me on how the files should be placed so that every thing works perfectly..

Code:

```
<link href="../../Content/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/css/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It's not full clear what syntax you use currently. Do you tried to use something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/YourFile.js") %>"></script>` or `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Url.Content ("~/Content/Site.css") %>" />`? Do you use bundles or includes separate files? How you reference images in your CSS? You should include the HTML or C# code which shows *how* you includes the resources on the page.

Comment: @Oleg..Upadted the question

Comment: @Oleg.Any more information required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you add jQuery UI in a wrong way to your project. You should validate that you copied `images` sub-folder of jQuery UI Theme in `Content\css` folder. If you opens `jquery-ui.css` and search for `url(` text you will see that `jquery-ui.css` uses *relative* paths to address images (for example `url(images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png)`). So you have to have `images` folder with all jQuery UI images from the Theme used.

By the way including of `jquery.ui.theme.css` is not required if you use `jquery-ui.css` from the same theme. Usage of old `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` seems to me not the best choice too. Instead of that you can use jQuery 2.0.3 (or 1.10.3 if you need support IE 6-8) or at least jQuery 1.9.2.

I personally prefer to use NuGet to add public packages to Visual Studio project. You need just open context menu of you Project in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio and choose "Manage NuGet Packages..". Then you can search online for public packages like `jQuery`, `jQuery.UI.Combined`, `jQuery.UI.Theme.Redmond`, `Trirand.jqGrid` and so on. NuGet would install all files in the corresponding folders of your project. The folder location was chosen by developer of the packages. Even if you would install some files manually I would recommend you to use the same locations of all files like the locations used by NuGet packages.

Comment: Wow.Now my grid looks wonderful with all the icons..Thanks Oleg for your valuble time

Comment: @Oleg.Yes..Sure i will take your sugesstions.

Comment: @Oleg..stackoverflow.com/questions/19383371/… can you help me on this?